# Expression Engine - How do I set the Category to show as dropdown?

Tags: expressionengine

I am using a SafeCracker form for data entry on a site and need to be able to display the category selection as a drop down list rather than multi-select.

I have this code here, but my attempts to modify it don't make any difference:

```
<p>
{category_menu}
    <label for="categories">Choose a category...</label><br />
    <select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4" multiple="single">
            {select_options}
    </select>
{/category_menu}
</p>
```

What is the correct way to set this to display a drop down list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is more of an HTML error. :) there's no such thing as multiple="single"

Just delete that completely and have:

```
<select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4">
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, it still shows as multi-select.

Comment: Ha! I figured it out size needs to be size="1"

Comment: Just remove size="1" altogether - 1 is the default.

Comment: @fmz just letting you know about our proposal for an EE specific site here (if you already are supporting it, you need to link your account so your reputation counts towards it) area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine

Comment: Hi Adrian, this is great news. Count me in.

Answer (score 1):

Could always try below, might work inside Safecracker (not tested)

```
<select name="my_custom_field">
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear"}   
<option value="{category_name}">{category_name}</option>
{/exp:channel:categories} 
</select>
```